# How can I multiply an obtained value of this query for the output value of another query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I am working on this query on a Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT
    tr.PolizzaID AS NumeroPolizza,
    pfr.FondoID AS CodiceFondo,
    '2016-09-30' AS dataRiferimentoPrezzo,
    SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0)) AS quote,
    SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0)) AS Controvalore
FROM
    TR_PrestazioneTotale tr WITH(nolock)

    ............................................................
    ............................................................
    DO SOME JOIN OPERATIONS
    ............................................................
    ............................................................

WHERE
    tr.PolizzaID = 1234567890
GROUP BY
    tr.PolizzaID,
    pfr.FondoID
HAVING 
    SUM(ISNULL(pre.impPre, 0) + ISNULL(riv.impRiv, 0)) <> 0
```

This query return always a **single value**.

As you can see one of the columns selected of the previous query is this one:

```
SUM(ISNULL(pre.impPre, 0) + ISNULL(riv.impRiv, 0)) AS Controvalore
```

that is a numeric value (something like **550058.8400**).

My problem is that I have to multiply this

```
SUM(ISNULL(pre.impPre, 0) + ISNULL(riv.impRiv, 0))
```

value for the output of this other query:

```
select Aliquota 
from TirAliquotaRamoI 
where DataElaborazione = '2016-09-30 00:00:00'
```

Also this query return always a **single value**.

So basically, the **Controvalore** output field of the first query have to be the result of **SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0))** multiplied by the **Aliquota** output value of the second query.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: No GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Why not join ?.

Comment: @jarlh yes I have als a GROUP BY clause, I have edited my original post

Comment: @sagi I have not post the full query with all the JOIN because it was too long. The original query works fine, I think that I have only to modify "SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0)) AS Controvalore" multipling it for the output value of the second query

Comment: Does the second query only return a single result as it is right now?  Does the first query only return a single a result? If not, then how would you know which `Aliquota` from that second query is to be multiplied by the first query's `Controvalore`? It's impossible to answer your question without knowing how your data looks, or at the very least, the output of these queries.

Comment: Please more details, returns select Aliquota from TirAliquotaRamoI where DataElaborazione = '2016-09-30 00:00:00' one value or what?

Comment: @JNevill yes, both the query return always a single record

Comment: @Frank yes, both the queries return always a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both return a single result, you can probably.. maybe get away with a subquery in your SELECT clause. I'm guessing by that `aliquota` name that this might work for your situation, but it really depends on the data underneath. At any rate, this is a good place to start.

```
SELECT
    tr.PolizzaID                                   AS NumeroPolizza,
    pfr.FondoID                                    AS CodiceFondo,
    '2016-09-30'                                   AS dataRiferimentoPrezzo,
    SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0)) AS quote,
    SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0)) * (select Aliquota from TirAliquotaRamoI where DataElaborazione = '2016-09-30 00:00:00') AS Controvalore
FROM
    TR_PrestazioneTotale tr WITH(nolock)

    ............................................................
    ............................................................
    DO SOME JOIN OPERATIONS
    ............................................................
    ............................................................

WHERE
    tr.PolizzaID = 1234567890
GROUP BY
tr.PolizzaID ,
pfr.FondoID
HAVING SUM(isnull(pre.impPre,0)+isnull(riv.impRiv,0)) <>0
```